# PHP - Multiple Api Call - Response time more then 15 seconds?

Tags: php, shopify

I need to get the order count for the last 30 days in a 1 day period. That´s what I wrote but the response time is 15 seconds and up. Is there any smarter strategy, maybe a Simultaneous asynchronous API call? I did not found a direct call to the orders api to receive the daily orders with one request. Any one any ideas?

Here´s my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)

{
    $timestamp = time();
    $tm = 86400 * $i; // 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400 = 1 day in seconds
    $tm = $timestamp - $tm;


    $the_date = date("Y-m-d", $tm);
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($the_date. ' + 1 days'));


    $orderinfo = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_min=".$the_date."&created_at_max=".$newdate, $array, 'GET');
    $orderinfo = json_decode($orderinfo['response'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    print_r($orderinfo);

}
```

Comment: To do an asynchronous call you'd need to find a library the supports promises or write your own call using something like guzzle http client.

Answer (score 1):

Hello as per your code you are calling shopify Api in a loop that's why it is taking time . So you can fetch last 30 days order first and after that you can easily distinguish order by order created date.

You can take reference by this api doc 
[Shopify order Api](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#index-2020-01)

In this doc you can fetch last 30 days order by created_at_min  filter